# Can we left shift a value inside a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, operators, bit-shift, unsigned-integer

I try to make use of a left shift to identify a setbit using a counter. When I try to left shift var, I found that it is stuck in an infinite loop and only zero gets printed.
What is wrong with the following code? Is it even legitimate to make use of a left shift inside a while loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int var =1;

    while(var<INT_MAX)
    {   
        var = var<<1;
        printf("%d\n", var);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since your condition is always true

Comment: When would `var<INT_MAX` ever be false?

Comment: Note that you are shifting a 1 only through the entire set of bits in the int.  Perhaps you're mind is inadvertently thinking you're adding a one with every shift; if you did that then the loop would end, but that's not being done.

Comment: Yo can try this  `do {...} while ( var != 1 << ((sizeof(int) * 8) - 1) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It perfectly fine to use a shift operation inside a loop.
The problem with your code is that `var` will never be equal or greater as `INT_MAX`.

For better understanding let me explain the problem on an 8 bit signed interger and not on a 32 bit signed integer.

You start with the value `var = 00000001b` (the `b` indicates that it is a binary number) and the `INT_MAX` for a 8 bit signed integer would be `INT_MAX = 01111111b = 127` (notice that the highest bit is 0, this is because it is the sign bit)

Now if you left shift `var` you are shifting this single 1 slowly to the right

```
var << 1 = 00000010b =    2
var << 2 = 00000100b =    4
var << 3 = 00001000b =    8
var << 4 = 00010000b =   16
var << 5 = 00100000b =   32
var << 6 = 01000000b =   64
var << 7 = 10000000b = -128
var << 8 = 00000000b =    0
var << 9 = 00000000b =    0
...
```

After the seventh shift the 1 bit reached the highest bit, but since we have an 8 bit signed integer we interprete `10000000b` not as `128` but as `-128` and so `var < INT_MAX` will always be true.

If you don't know why this happens you may want to read on [two complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) numbers.

**Edit:**
More formally, like Andrew Henle pointed out: shifting an value outside the range of its type is not defined.
The result ot the operation `x << y` must be equal to `x * 2^y` and if `x * 2 ^y` is not representable with the type the result is not defined.

So the table from above looks more like

```
var << 1 = 00000010b =      2
var << 2 = 00000100b =      4
var << 3 = 00001000b =      8
var << 4 = 00010000b =     16
var << 5 = 00100000b =     32
var << 6 = 01000000b =     64
var << 7 = undef.    = undef.
var << 8 = undef.    = undef.
var << 9 = undef.    = undef.
...
```

Comment: Left-shift of a signed value that is negative is [undefined  behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4): "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2):

In this loop

```
while(var<INT_MAX)
{   
    var = var<<1;
    printf("%d\n", var);        
}
```

var never can be equal to INT_MAX because only one bit is set in it

int var =1;

that is shifted.

Try the following loop:

```
while(var<INT_MAX)
{   
    var = ( var << 1 ) + 1;
    printf("%d\n", var);        
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program where for simplicity instead of the signed type int there is used the signed type signed char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) 
{
    signed char var = 1;

    while ( var  < SCHAR_MAX )
    {   
        var = ( var << 1 )  + 1;
        printf( "%d\n",  var );        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
7
15
31
63
127
```

And according to the C Standard (5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`)

```
— maximum value for an object of type signed char
SCHAR_MAX +127 // 2^7 − 1
```